# Javascript: Get values from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
{
"4": {
    "struttura": "Museo Archeologico",
    "casse": [{
        "id": "5",
        "nome": "Cassa a Terra DEMO"
    }]
},
"5": {
    "struttura": "Museo Fabrice",
    "casse": [{
        "id": "6",
        "nome": "Cassa Fabrice"
    }]
}}
```

i have this  object in javascript. is it possible to have "casse", based on the key (4, or 5)

Comment: you mean like ... `x["4"].casse`? where `x` is the variable that holds that object? then, yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
"4": {
    "struttura": "Museo Archeologico",
    "casse": [{
        "id": "5",
        "nome": "Cassa a Terra DEMO"
    }]
},
"5": {
    "struttura": "Museo Fabrice",
    "casse": [{
        "id": "6",
        "nome": "Cassa Fabrice"
    }]
}}
```

The following should do the trick as @Bravo described:

```
console.log(data["4"].casse)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {
 "4": {
    "struttura": "Museo Archeologico",
    "casse": [{
        "id": "5",
        "nome": "Cassa a Terra DEMO"
    }]
 },
 "5": {
    "struttura": "Museo Fabrice",
    "casse": [{
        "id": "6",
        "nome": "Cassa Fabrice"
    }]
 }}
 let i = 4;
 console.log(obj[i].casse);
```

This will get you there even when the key is a number